# flexbox: how to make boxes fill width, but not when row is not completely full

Tags: css, flexbox

Hi hopefully my question makes sense.  I am trying to use flexbox to create a grid system similar to bootstrap or foundation's.  I want each row to fill up the entire width of the screen, but only of that row is completely full. For example, if I have five boxes, with three boxes fitting on each row, I want the first row to span the entire width while the second row only takes up 2/3 of the width.  all the boxes would maintain the same size.  currently I am using flex-grow:

```
HTML

<div id="portfoliobox">
  <div class="workbox"></div>
  <div class="workbox"></div>
  <div class="workbox"></div>
  <div class="workbox"></div>
  <div class="workbox"></div>
</div>

CSS

#portfoliobox{
display: -webkit-flex;
flex-direction: row;
flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.workbox{
width:380px;
height:200px;
background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
margin: 10px;
flex-grow: 1;

display:block;

}
```

This is all I have so far, and when the 4th and 5th boxes are moved to the second row, they both stretch out to take up the entire width.  I want them to maintain the same size as boxes 1 to 3.  However, I want these all the rows to stretch the entire width of its parent container.

hopefully my question is clear enough.

Comment: Something like https://jsfiddle.net/cqmwqgbj/1/ ?

Comment: Flexbox is not intended to replace grid systems and the behaviour you require is not something flexbox can achieve natively. Flexbox width/heights are consistent inside rows and not from row to row.